# Conexão entre Node e Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, react

estou criando uma API em Node para um projeto pessoal com conexão com Postgresql. Há alguma forma de realizar um migrate (para que os registros sejam criados automaticamente no banco) a partir de models criados? Sei como isso pode ser feito utilizando o mongoose (Conexão para o MongoDB) com o:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = mongoose.model('Product');

module.exports = {  

    async store(req, res) {

        const products = await Product.create(req.body);

        return res.json(products);
    },
}
```

Mas neste projeto as entidades do meu banco possuem relações. Alguma ideia? Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) deve resolver seu problema, só mapear as tabelas para os models, depois é só criar as seeds e os migrates, para eu é um dos melhores ORM, utilizo a muito tempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o sequelize para banco de dados relacionais como o Postgres ou o MySql.

```
sudo yarn add sequelize
```

neste [link](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/getting-started.html) tem a documentação para as configurações

depois é so dar um `sudo yarn sequelize db:create`

espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar a conexão com o banco de dados Postgres, você pode utilizar o Sequelize.

[Documentação do sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)

Para criar uma nova migration você deve utilizar o comando:

```
yarn sequelize migration:create --name=nome-migration
```

E para cria-lá no banco basta executar:

```
yarn sequelize db:migrate
```

Lembre-se que para poder utilizar os comandos para criar as migrations, antes é necessario configurar o Sequelize no seu projeto.

[Artigo para você configurar o Sequelize no seu projeto](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/nodejs-express-sequelize/)